# CSS Grid: Picture overflow in height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple CSS grid with 2 columns (60%, 40%). The first one is filled with a picture.
The picture is well contained inside the grid when it has enough height.

The problem is when it has not enough height, the picture is overflowing in height.
I would like it to stay inside the grid and fill it whatever the window size.

**Here's the code:**

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="picture" src="https://i.pinimg.com/550x/e4/7e/00/e47e006f1cf838ccf5468e8548a7577c.jpg">
  <p class="text">Some text</p>
</div>
```

**Here's a JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/f4us5krq/1/

Comment: Remove the .container height and check!

Comment: Ok it works but I would like my container to have a fixed width of 100vh

Comment: you need min-height:0 on the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your height on your container to be 100% and that way the picture will fit inside. You can try `overflow: hidden;` on the .picture if you still want to use `height: 100vh;`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="picture" src="https://i.pinimg.com/550x/e4/7e/00/e47e006f1cf838ccf5468e8548a7577c.jpg">
  <p class="text">Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` was the trick

Comment: @William Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Change `width` and `height` to `inherit`. Add max width/height to stop overflow if the grid is too tight.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.picture {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="picture" src="https://i.pinimg.com/550x/e4/7e/00/e47e006f1cf838ccf5468e8548a7577c.jpg">
  <p class="text">Some text</p>
</div>
```

P.S you can also experiment with `object-fit: contain`

Comment: It will create white-space on large screens